# How to add product description in paypal through html hidden field?

Tags: html, paypal, hidden

I want to add my product description to paypal shopping cart and I am using html hidden fields to send form data.

can anyone suggest what should I pass inorder to display product description?

Thanks in advance for your co-operation.

Comment: which language are you using? and a bit more detail and code please

Comment: I am using PHP language and I am sending value through HTML hidden fields like this: <input type="hidden" name="?" value="?" />

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the Description field "Add a description" on the payment site then @deGales is wrong and @aditya menon is right. The on0 and os0 parameters are used for options like size:S.

**Example:**

```
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="T-shirt" />
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size">
<input type="hidden" name="os0" value="S">
```

and

```
$data['item_name'] = $_POST['item_name'];
$data['on0'] = $_POST['on0'];
$data['os0'] = $_POST['os0'];
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was here looking for an answer to a similar problem but ended up trying it and figuring it out on my own.  For what it's worth:

I was looking to use on0, on1 and so forth to show what options a user had selected from my site.  It seems all the examples here are for carts using xclick instead of upload.

I was using upload so my items are listed in an itemized fashion:

```
    item_name_1 => "some item"
    item_name_2 => "another item"
```

if you wish to use the optional variables on0 / os1 you'll have to add the corresponding number to the end of them as well to get them to show up at checkout.

```
    item_name_1 => "some item"
    quantity_1 => "3"
    amount_1 => "2.00"
    on0_1 => "Color"
    os0_1 => "Blue"
    on1_1 => "Size"
    os1_1 => "Large"
```

you would increment the number after the underscore for each item in the cart!

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Description Here">
```

A reference to all HTML hidden values can be found here...

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables